# Deleting files with ^? in their name

Tags: bash, unix, special-characters, rm, backspace

I have a file called `^?x` (thats `^?` the backspace character). I have no idea how it got that way, but I need to get rid of it. Except when I try to do `rm` I don't really know what to type. How can I delete the file?

Comment: because your question is off-topic.  It should be on superuser or one of the linux/unix sites.

Comment: Unix issues overlap SO, SU and unix. All are good.

Comment: Often times, your terminal emulator will emit the control character after hitting `[C-v]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have other files that end in `x`?  If not, just `rm *x` will do it.  If you do need to type it directly, you can use `\010` which is the octal sequence for the backspace character.

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend `rm -i *x`, or since it's one character `rm -r ?x`

Comment: `^?` is the DEL character, not backspace. Backspace is represented as `^H`. But octal sequences aren't automatically translated in shell commands; if I type `rm \010` my shell just ignores the backslash. In bash you can use `rm $'\010'` -- or, in this case, `rm $'\177x`

Comment: Oops, typo, I meant `-i` (interactive)